# Symfony : Route PUT method

Tags: symfony

Anyone knows why the PUT method doesn't work using PHP Symfony?
If I replace PUT to POST everything works fine

```
    /**
    * @Route("/api/product/update", name="product_udpate", methods = {"PUT"})
    */
```

i am reading variables like that

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
echo $request->request->get('name');
```

error:
 No route found for "PUT /api/product/update/23" (404 Not Found)

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after the modification?

Comment: i've just tried , but it doesn't work either :-(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not creating the route correctly. Basically, you need to add the "id" to the route.

```php
/**
 * @Route("/api/product/update/{id}", name="product_udpate", methods = {"PUT"})
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Your logic here
    $name = $request->get('name');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the following error because you have not configured route correctly.

```
error: No route found for "PUT /api/product/update/23" (404 Not Found)
```

If you want to add id along with your desire url, you have to define in your route.
Thus, you can update your route:

```
  /**
    * @Route("/api/product/update/{id}", name="product_udpate", methods = {"PUT"}, defaults={"id"=null})
    */
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the symfony documentation [How to Use HTTP Methods beyond GET and POST in Routes](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html)

> Unfortunately, life isn't quite this simple, since most browsers do not support sending PUT and DELETE requests via the method attribute in an HTML form. Fortunately, Symfony provides you with a simple way of working around this limitation. By including a _method parameter in the query string or parameters of an HTTP request, Symfony will use this as the method when matching routes

So you have to **fake the method** like this one :

```
<form action='your route'>
  <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PUT'>
  //do something.......
</form>
```

Comment: i am creating a restAPI i am sending data in PUT with POSTMAN

Comment: Try this :
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();